# How to handle error or return value with a method

Tags: scala, error-handling

I want to test, if the value is a Throwable, if it is, I want to print out an error message.

If the value is not a Throwable, I want to return it.

I have this code, which gives me following error message, when Im hovering over the "value" which sould be returned in the last line:

> Found: (value : Either[Throwable, A]) Required: A )

```
def throwAndPlayAgainOrGet[A](value: Either[Throwable, A]): A =
{
    if(value.isLeft) println("error: " + value) + playAgain
    value
}
```

My Question:

how can I do that?

Comment: also asked at https://users.scala-lang.org/t/how-to-handle-error-or-return-value/8609

Comment: Okey, so you found a throwable, you print it, and now what? Does the program stop?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez no the program is calling the playAgain function with the following signature: **def playAgain: ZIO[Console, Throwable, Has[Any]]**

Comment: I don't understand exactly how to fits the code you provided, but anyways. It seems you should rather lift that `Either` into the `ZIO`

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching for this:

```scala
def throwAndPlayAgainOrGet[A](value: Either[Throwable, A]): A = value match {
  case Left(err) => {
    println(err)
    someDefaultAValue // or throw err
  }
  case Right(v) => v
}
```

Comment: thanks, but another silly question: what can I use as a default value and how to implement that? :)

Comment: @helloworld it depends on your logic and what are you trying to achieve.